# Testing constraints/restrictions in multiple regression using R

Tags: r, multiple-regression, constrained-regression

I have a Cobb-Douglas equation I am modelling in `R`:

$$
\ln⁡(Y) = β + β_a \ln⁡(A) + β_l \ln⁡(L) + β_f \ln⁡(F) + β_o \ln⁡(O) + u
$$

Is there an easy way of testing the hypothesis about whether the betas sum to one; less than one; more than one?

Comment: The [car package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/car/) has the `linearHypothesis` function that enables you to test the claim that all betas sum to 1 easily. If `mod` is your model, then use the following command: `linearHypothesis(mod, "1 = beta_a + beta_l + beta_f + beta_o")` where `beta` are the names of your variables $\ln(A)$ etc. as entered in the regression command. Have a look at the help page of `linearHypothesis` for more examples.

Comment: Cool! Please ask again if you need further help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Testing linear restriction in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/211584/testing-linear-restriction-in-r)