# Testing linear restriction in R

Tags: r, regression, econometrics

I would like to test a linear restriction in R. Instead of the usual $\beta_i=0$, I want to test if $\beta_k=0.5$ and $\beta_j=-0.5$.

Is there a way to do this using lm command, and just writing a different formula for the models that lm command uses?

I was thinking of writing $y-0.5x_k+0.5x_j=\sum_{i\neq j,k} x_i\beta_i+(\beta_k-0.5)x_k+(\beta_j+0.5)x_j$. However, I'm not sure how to code this reparametrization...

P.S:Would writing $y−I(−0.5x_k+0.5x_j)$ ~ $\sum x_i$ as the formula to be run on lm, work as 2 t-tests?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your current parameterization is sufficient to test *either* coefficient restriction (via the t-tests for each coefficient), but not *both* restrictions at the same time. To do that one can conduct an [F-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test#Regression_problems) between the unrestricted and the restricted model (since it is nested).

Example below in R using the `car` package.

```
library(car)
set.seed(10)
x1 <- rnorm(100)
x2 <- rnorm(100)
x3 <- rnorm(100)
y <- 5*x1 + 0.5*x2 - 0.5*x3 + rnorm(100)
m1 <- lm(y~x1+x2+x3)
linearHypothesis(m1,c("x2 = 0.5","x3 = -0.5"),test="F")
```

Which then spits out a table with the RSS for each model and the degrees of freedom, needed to calculate the F-statistic.

```
Linear hypothesis test

Hypothesis:
x2 = 0.5
x3 = - 0.5

Model 1: restricted model
Model 2: y ~ x1 + x2 + x3

  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
1     98 107.21                           
2     96 107.10  2   0.10752 0.0482  0.953
```

---

You answered you own question in terms of testing individual coefficients, you can transform the variable on the left hand side. To replicate the `linearHypothesis` function I trick R here by making the transformed variable:

```
#equivalent F test - can trick R by making y a new variable
y <- y -0.5*x2 +0.5*x3
m2 <- lm(y~x1)
anova(m2,m1)
```

Which reproduces the earlier table. You can use this same trick to get the default summary t-test's in the regression output to test against the alternative hypotheses:

```
#test for either coefficient restriction (with updated y)
m3 <- lm(y~x1+x2+x3)
summary(m3)
#you can see m3 is equivalent to m1 - just changes the location of the test
#anova(m1,m3)
```

Which produces for coefficient estimates:

```
Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.208282   0.107351   1.940   0.0553 .  
x1           5.045149   0.112973  44.658   <2e-16 ***
x2           0.033042   0.110693   0.299   0.7660    
x3          -0.004875   0.110122  -0.044   0.9648
```

To test with the original values, user2864849 answers that question. You just subtract out the null from the point estimate and use the same standard error. So using the coefficients from `m1` you can see below `t_est` reproduces the t-statistic in model 3.

```
#to see how it is just the original t-test with the location changed for x2
pt_est <- summary(m1)$coefficients[3,1] #point estimate x2
se_est <- summary(m1)$coefficients[3,2] #standard error x2
t_est <- (pt_est - 0.5)/se_est          #t-stat for null of 0.5
t_est
```

Comment: Andy, thanks for your answer. If I was interested in doing the t-tests, how would I do it in R? I do not know how to code that part as a formula for the lm command. This is what I'm more interested about.

Comment: Andy, should I write '$y-I(-0.5x_k+0.5x_j) $ ~ $ \sum x_i$' as the formula to be run on lm?

Comment: Yep - you already answered your own question if that is the case.

Comment: Hi, is there a restriction test for time series models such as GARCH model? I cannot apply this 'linearHypothesis' onto my GARCH model at all.

Comment: I presume you can construct whatever hypothesis test manually using the parameter estimates and the variance/covariance matrix as the other answers have illustrated.

Answer (score 1):

You can test the hypothesized value of $\beta_k$ much in the same way that it would be tested for $\beta_k = 0$. You can get a t-value on n-2 df with the formula:

$$T = \frac{\beta_i- hypothesezed~~ \beta_i}{Standard~~ Error~~ \beta_i}$$

In many cases this simplifies to beta over standard error because making the hypothesis be zero removes it from the equation.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to test the hypothesis of the form $R\beta = r$. In your case:
$$\underbrace{\left[ \begin{array}{cccc} \ldots & 1& 0 & \ldots \\ \ldots & 0& 1 & \ldots  \end{array}\right]}_R \underbrace{\left[ \begin{array}{c}\ldots \\ \beta_j \\ \beta_k \\ \ldots \end{array} \right]}_\beta = \underbrace{\left[ \begin{array}{c}-.5 \\ .5 \end{array} \right]}_r $$

Let $\hat{\beta}$ be your regression estimates of $\beta$. Under the condition that $\hat{\beta} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\beta, \Sigma \right)$ conditional on data $X$ (eg. $\hat{\beta}$ asymptotically normal with mean $\beta$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$) then the linear restrictions $R \beta = r$ can be tested with a $\chi^2$ test. Observe that $R\hat{\beta}-r$ would be normal with  $Var(R \hat{\beta} - r\mid X) = R \Sigma R'$. Then we would have:
$$(R\hat{\beta} - r)' \left( R \Sigma R' \right)^{-1} (R \hat{\beta} - r) \sim \chi^2_{\#r}$$
Where $\#r$ is the number of restrictions (in your case two).

The most classic way though is to do an F-test. This would take the form:
$$(R\hat{b} - r)' \left(R \Sigma R' \right)^{-1} (R\hat{b} - r) / (\#r)\sim F(\#r, n- k) $$
where $\Sigma$ is estimate of $Var(\hat{\beta} \mid X)$ and $\#r$ is the number of restrictions (note rank of R should be $\#r$.)

See Fumio Hayashi *Econometrics* p. 65-66